# Working of K-apriori Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, data-mining

I am trying to develop a java code for data mining algorithm i.e. **k-apriori algorithm** which improves the performance of apriori algorithm. As I have already developed 1) **apriori** & 2) **apriori based on boolean matrix**. The thing which I am not able to understand is how the ***wiener function*** helps to transform the data. Why we use it in this algorithm. I tried to search over google for example of K-apriori algorithm but not able to find any example. I know the working of **K-means** algorithm. If any one have example K-apriori as specially how it works it will be helpful.
[Here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ijser.org%2Fresearchpaper%255CImproving-the-Efficiency-of-Web-Usage-Mining-Using-K-Apriori-and-FP-Growth-Algorithm.pdf&ei=S8LLVPb6E4P5mAWmtYHYDA&usg=AFQjCNG5JizFDja04x63Te2QI6sJkj2eTw&sig2=oz6A0nj5WyWO4bIm-k87Nw&bvm=bv.84607526,d.dGY&cad=rja) is the link from which I am referring the K-apriori algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never implemented k-apriori myself but if I am right it is just Apriori working in K clusters found by K-means

As you know K-means is based on the concept of cluster centroids. Usually the binary data clustering is done by using 0 and 1 as numerical value. But that is very problematic when it comes to calculating centroids from data. If you have binary data distance between two points is just number of bits that are different between two points. You can read more about this problem in [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21477401)

To get any meaningful clusters K-means should operate on real values. And that's why you use wiener function to transform binary values into real values which helps K-means get satisfying results

Wiener function - They perform it on each binary vector as follows:

1. Calculate the mean µ for the input vector Xi around each element
2. Calculate the variance σ^2 of each element
3. Perform wiener transformation for each element in the vector using equation Y based on its neighborhood

Assuming you have binary matrix size X of size pxq and vector V which is n-th row of that matrix. Let choose neighbourhood window 3. For n-th position of V vector

µ = 1/3 * ( V[n-1] + V[n] + V[n+1] )

σ^2 = 1/3 * ( ( V[n-1]-µ )^2 + ( V[n]-µ )^2 + ( V[n+1]-µ )^2 )

Y[n] = µ + (σ^2 - λ^2)/σ^2 * ( V[n] - µ )

where λ^2 is the average of all the local estimated variances, so f.e. assuming length of vector V = 5:

λ^2 = (σ^2[0]+σ^2[1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21477401)+σ^2[2]+σ^2[3]+σ^2[4])/5

Comment: @ZpBany yes! you are right but how does wiener function does it. I tried to implement that formula but unable to do so. According to me it is not enough to provide formula without giving example of how it works? Do you know any implementation on wiener function. As far I know it is implemented in MATLAB for restoring an image but unfortunately it doesn't helped me to grab real data. If you have any code that can be used instead wiener or implementation of wiener it will be helpful for me

Comment: @VighaneshGursale i have added some info about how to calculate wiener function. It is clear enough?

Comment: your explanation is correct. Thank you very much and it is very much easy to understand, but I have doubt, you've specified that neighbourhood window 3 what does it mean? and why you generated the average of 5 variances only? Please clear my doubt.

Comment: @VighaneshGursale Ok, sorry, I forgot to mention that that was example assuming length of V vector equal to 5. Of course you just have to add them all and divide by V length. Neighbourhood window just specify how many elements do you consider when you analyze n-th element. If you choose it f.e. equal to five than µ = 1/5 * ( V[n-2] + V[n-1] + V[n] + V[n+1] + V[n+2] ) and σ^2 also take more elements in sum. Just look in this article  at Fig. 4. Window or mask of size 5 in 1D

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I've now implemented the code. :)